# How to use && and conditional operator

Tags: javascript

i am getting error if i use while creating an object.

```
"ok_count": s.status !== (-3 && -2 && -1 && 0 && 1) ? "1" : "0"
```

Do anyone have any idea how can i use conditional operator with Logical &

Comment: There is no syntax error in the code you posted, unless `s` is `undefined`. The `&&` expression does not make any sense, but it is syntactically correct.

Comment: `(-3 && -2 && -1 && 0 && 1)` will always be `0`. The conditional operator is irrelevant  here.

Comment: @Quentin but i am creating an an object here and then pushing it into an array, can you please suggest how can i check for conditions here if conditional operator doesnt work here.

Comment: @BhutaGorilla — The conditional operator is fine. The problem is the condition. The duplicate question covers that.

Answer (score 2):

You have to individually compare each value

```
"ok_count": (s.status !== -3 && s.status !== -2 && s.status !== -1 && s.status !==0 && s.status !==1) ? "1" : "0"
```

or you can use a shortcut with an array includes method like

```
"ok_count": ![-3, -2, -1, 0, 1].includes(s.status) ? "1" : "0"
```

or if your range is continues you can use `>= and <=` operators

```
"ok_count": (s.status >= -3 && s.status <= 1)? "1" : "0"
```

Comment: bhai thanks alot, really means alot.

Comment: Glad it helped you :-D

Comment: i had one more ques but i guess i cant ask here due to only 3 ques policy of stack overflow can i ask it here in comments? its about how can i change the value of a key in an array.